# Could a Provider choose between different instances

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a setup where i bind multiple instances of one class. The difference between the classes is one input param. The two instances is always injected.

The bindings looks like this.

```
CmsExportAwsWriterSingle cmsExportAwsWriterSingleTranslation = new CmsExportAwsWriterSingle("testing-v1", getCredentials(id, secret));
bind(CmsExportWriter.class)
.annotatedWith(Names.named("config:export.writer.translation"))
.toInstance(cmsExportAwsWriterSingleTranslation);

CmsExportAwsWriterSingle cmsExportAwsWriterSingleReview = new CmsExportAwsWriterSingle("prod-v1", getCredentials(id, secret));
bind(CmsExportWriter.class)
.annotatedWith(Names.named("config:export.writer.review"))
.toInstance(cmsExportAwsWriterSingleReview);
```

Now I have two Services which uses javax.inject Provider to give me a instance of a writer.

```
@Inject
public ServiceOne(Provider<CmsExportWriter> writer) {
   CmsExportWriter writer = writer.get();
}

@Inject
public ServiceTwo(Provider<CmsExportWriter> writer) {
   CmsExportWriter writer = writer.get();
}
```

Is there any way to make the provider give me correct instances of the classes I injected in the set up?

E.g If I want `ServiceOne` to get the Writer named `"config:export.writer.translation"`
And `ServiceTwo` to get `"config:export.writer.review"`

Or do I have to abandond the provider and use `@Named`in the constructors of the services.

```
public ServiceTwo(@Named("config:export.writer.review") CmsExportWriter writer)
```

Just using @Named wont give me the perks as Provider does. And I need it to be new instances of the writers each time.

Looks like the way to go is to inject the Providers instead.

Answer (score 0):

The provider serves for creating a new instance on each call to its get method. This is appropriate to the case, when a dependency instance cannot/should not be injected upon creation of the enclosing object or if multiple instances are needed etc. This does nothing with injection for multiple bindings.

The proper way to inject instances with multiple bindings is via binding annotations. There are two types of binding annotations: build-in @Named annotation  or custom annotation, which should be implemented according to the standard template.

You can find some examples [here](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/12/practical-guide-to-guice-part2.html)